# TThread Access Violating on Terminate/Free

Tags: c++, tthread

I am running a short bit of code that will occasionally (very rarely) Access Violate on the Terminate/Free of my TThread.  I am running many instances of these threads but this spot seems to be the only ones that is causing problems and it only does so once every 500 or so calls.

```
TThreadInheritor* Base= new TThreadInheritor(1);
  try {
    Base->Start();
    WaitForSingleObject((HANDLE)Base->Handle, 1000);
    MyBaseId = Base->scanvalue;
  }__finally {
    Base->Terminate();
    Base->Free();
  }
```

It is being thrown in my finally.  My first guess was that WaitForSingleObject was timing out in a weird way and causing the Terminate and Free to mess up, but I'm not quite sure how that would happen.  I didn't change anything to do with the Terminate/Free methods when I inherited from TThread.

Anyone know what could cause those two methods to access violate after so little code?

Comment: Well, you could certainly start by at least _checking the return value_ of `WaitForSingleObject`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never free a `TThread` that is still running.  The base class `TThread` destructor is not safe in that regard.  It does some pretty stupid things that can cause problems.  ALWAYS make sure a `TThread` is fully terminated before freeing it.  Use the `WaitFor()` method, or wait until `WaitForSingleObject()` reports `WAIT_OBJECT_0`.

Comment: Ah okay.  I was mistakenly assuming that Terminate would run synchronously with the calling thread.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, do not use `Base->Free()`. Use `delete Base;` instead.

More importantly, you should call `Base->WaitFor()` after `Terminate()` to make sure it is actually terminated prior to deleting the object.

```
Base->Terminate();
Base->WaitFor();
delete Base;
```

Otherwise you'd be deleting the thread object (which your code / RTL may still be using) prematurely thus leading to the occasional access violation.

Or you could set the `FreeOnTerminate` property to true and forget about waiting / deleting the object altogether (be careful about running out of virtual memory though if you have too many threads since there's no 64-bit version of C++ Builder yet).

Comment: Why should I not call base->Free()?  If it an unsafe function I would imagine that it would not be included in the class.

Comment: `TThread` derives from `TObject`, which is a Delphi class with a compatibility wrapper in C++. `Free()` is a method of `TObject`, which is why it exists in C++ at all, but it is only really used in Delphi. It should not be used in C++, always keep `new` and `delete` balanced in C++ instead. The compiler knows the class is based in Delphi and will make sure `delete` will destruct it correctly.